# Примеры использования __proto__ и prototype в реальных задачах

Tags: javascript, prototype, прототипное-наследование

Подскажите в каких случаях использование `__proto__` и `prototype` сильно облегчает жизнь.

В каких конкретно сайтах и для чего они используются в них  (может есть **классы задач** для их применения)?

Приведите примеры кода (желательно характерное).

Comment: нет таких случаев, всегда можно обойтись без прототипов.

Comment: просто пример использования можешь посмотреть открыв `jQuery`